# How to prove the continuity of an implicit surface?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, surfaces, implicit-function

Let $f$ be an arbitrary function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $S$ be an implicit surface defined by
$$
S = \lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^2,\quad f(x) = 0 \rbrace
$$

**How can I prove that the implicit surface $S$ is continuous?**

I feel like if $f$ is continuous, then $S$ is also continuous, but I do not know how to prove it rigorously. And I do not know if the other way is true (if $S$ is continuous, then $f$ is continuous).

I don't know how to specify a criteria about the fact that $S$ is continuous. I am trying to define two points $x,y\in S$ (so $f(x)=(y)=0$), such that $\|x - y\| < \epsilon$, $\forall\epsilon>0$. I am trying to check what happen when $x\rightarrow y$, while $x$ "stays" in $S$, but I cannot go anywhere with that.

Should I take the definition of continuity in terms of limit of function, limit of sequence, neighborhood, ...?

Should I use the gradient $\partial f$ of $f$ (which defines an orthogonal vector to the surface)? Should I impose some conditions on the gradient, like bounds, non-nullity or continuity?

Comment: If you consider **arbitrary** functions $f$, then the level set can be **extremely** badly behaved: for any closed set $E\subset\Bbb{R}^n$, there is a $C^{\infty}$ function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $E=f^{-1}(\{0\})$. Since closed sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$ can be extremely crazy, what you're asking about is false, even if you impose all the smoothness assumptions on the function.

Comment: Usually, when we want to talk about smooth level sets, we assume that $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ is a smooth function with nowhere-vanishing gradient (i.e smooth function + conditions on its derivative). Then, the zero level set is a smooth hypersurface (you can generalize this theorem further; google *regular-value theorem*). This follows by the implicit function theorem, and such matters are discussed in any good textbook.

Comment: What, this $S$ *is a continuous set*, means?